# Can not find route in mini3 MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Good day, actually want to use a very small MVC framework in my application, i stumbled into MINI3 in github.com which i love and will like to use but i cant actually find the file that registers routes. i thought there will be a route.php or web.php file that i can use to register my route, but to no avail.
Please can anyone help me out for the file that registers route?

Here is the link https://github.com/panique/mini3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such file but alternatively you can use application/core/application.php to alter it's behavior. All you need is to check your get variables and bring appropriate method.